# showlabel: shift equation label up

Tags: showlabels

My document has many long displayed, numbered equations.  When I use `\showlabel` sometimes the equation label overlaps with the displayed equations.  Is it possible to tweak the `\showlabel` parameters so that the equation labels (and equation labels only) are shifted up a bit, e.g. like in `\showkeys`? I don't have to use a smaller font for the label, and since this applies only in displayed equation environment there is plenty of v-space.

(I hope I didn't bring up a sacrilegious topic!)

THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: Did the provided answer help?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner:  Yes it does --- thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please consider accepting the provided answer if it was helpful )checkmark symbol next to the answer), see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two half-answers, and a prospective answer.

You can adjust the formatting of labels with `\showlabelsetlabel`, as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showlabels}
\def\showlabelsetlabel#1{\raise2ex\hbox{\fbox{\showlabelfont #1}}}
\begin{document}
Here is an equation, Eq.\ref{eq1}.
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq1}
  E=mc^2.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

That applies to all labelled things.  You also suggest that you'd like to showlabels for different things differently.  You can do that with the optional argument to `\showlabels`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showlabels}
\usepackage{color}
\showlabels[\color{green}]{ref}
\begin{document}
Here is an equation, Eq.\ref{eq1}.
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq1}
  E=mc^2.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

What you *can't* do is give that optional argument as, for example `\showlabels[\fbox]{ref}`, using a one-arg formatting command.

...until version 1.9.  Doing this seems such a good idea that I've made the (small) change required to make this possible, and that will be available when v1.9 is released, which might as well be soon.

Comment: Version 1.9 is now available on CTAN (a slightly odd definition of ‘soon’, I know, but this went right out of my mind).